# Display count of Selected items in a <select multiple>

Tags: javascript, select, count

Tried all the answers on this q, but just can't get the count to display (or maybe the js to run?)
Here's my code .. I want the current count of selected items to update each time I select another

Any advice appreciated .. learning every day

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/Javascript">
function count_cars() {
 var options = document.getElementById("cars").options, count = 0 ;
 for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
 if (options[i].selected) count++; 
} // end of for loop
// now put the current count in the element with id='car_count'
document.getElementById("car_count").innerHTML = count ;
} // end of function
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="test1" method="GET" action="test2.html">
How many cars have you got?
<table>
<tr><td>

<select multiple name="cars[]" value="" onchange="count_cars">
  <option value="ford" >Ford </option>
  <option value="saab" >Saab </option>
  <option value="merc" >Merc </option>
  <option value="audi" >Audi </option>
</select>

</td><td>Total : <div id="car_count"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You were trying to access the select list option by id - but the select did not have an id. Also - its better to indent your code in a more readable fashion.

```js
function count_cars() {
 var options = document.getElementById("cars").options, count = 0 ;
 for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
   if (options[i].selected) count++; 
  } // end of for loop
 document.getElementById("car_count").innerHTML = count ;
} // end of function
```

```html
<form name="test1" method="GET" action="test2.html">
How many cars have you got?
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select multiple id="cars" name="cars[]" value="" onchange="count_cars()">
          <option value="ford" >Ford </option>
          <option value="saab" >Saab </option>
          <option value="merc" >Merc </option>
          <option value="audi" >Audi </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        Total : <div id="car_count"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter feature.

```
const options =  document.getElementById("cars").options;
const count = [...options].filter(option => option.selected).length;
```

Don't forget to set an the `cars` id to your select.

Comment: Perfect. New eyes saw I was using name instead of id.
Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectedOptions.

It contains a list of the  elements contained within the  element that are currently selected.

It is an HTMLCollection object with one entry per currently selected option

```
var count = document.getElementById("cars").selectedOptions.length;
```

and display it using

```
document.getElementById("car_count").innerHTML = count ;
```